# Как вытащить из Bootstrap кнопки-переключатели и как их использовать?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Как вытащить  из Bootstrap [кнопки-переключатели](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) типа "Radio"?
Как их использовать? Там нет никаких тэгов радиокнопок.
Как кнопки будут передавать переменные (нужно использовать для переключателя
на сайте)? Или они только в качестве ссылок используются?

Comment: а зачем ? подключите бутстрап и используйте, если вам их интерфейс нравится.

Comment: Нужно стили поменять будет.

Comment: так может и поменять css ? смотрите как делаются темы для бутстрапа.http://stylebootstrap.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Смотрите на код

   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
    </div>
2. Вытаскиваете из css всё, что относится к этим элементам (сверяете по class)
3. Пишите свой js или вытаскиваете из ихнего. Нужно получить js код, который реагирует на нажатия
4. That's all